# File upload param not showing in Swagger UI 3.0

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-3.0

I am creating swagger document using annotations in springboot application, all the APIs params are working instead of **file** param, **file** param is not being shown in the swagger UI. It is also not giving any errors in the logs related to the **file** attribute.

Below is the annotation being used to display the **file** param.

```java
@ApiImplicitParam(name="mediafile", value="upload the file", dataTypeClass="File.class", required=true, paramType="form")
```

I also have changed `paramType="formData"` but still file attribute is still not showing up. Any help will be appreciated. Swagger = v3.0